# Print data from wordpress sql query

Tags: query

```
global $wpdb;
$video = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_video");
```

`$video` has no value when do echo, and when I do `print_r($video)`, it has a value

```
print_r($video) = Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [naslov] => [opis] => [link] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhbE ) )
```

Comment: if `$video` is an array then it wont print values on echo. But will display array values on `print_r($video)`

Comment: <?php echo $video->link; ?> has no value

Comment: add full output of `print_r($video);` in your question by [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/165779/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's not a simple array but a multi level array, so you can not simply use `<?php echo $video->link; ?>`. It wont print anything because $video array does not have any child item named `link` but `link` is the item of a child array.

So if you are certain that you only need to get `link` value of first child array then use this.

```
<?php echo $video[0]->link; ?>
```

But if your array has more child arrays and you want to return values of each then you can run a foreach loop.

```
foreach ( $video as $key => $vid ) {
    echo $vid->link;
}
```